# (Atlas + Realm) How to use Realm's App Services Secrets in Custom JWT uri for Authentication Providers?

Tags: mongodb, realm, atlas

I'm trying to use a secret in Realm to hide the authentication endpoint for my custom JWT authentication process. The security team doesn't want that available in the UI, and there are no examples on how to use secrets or environment variables for the JWK URI when using Custom JWT providers.

How would I do that for `jwkURI`? I can only set "jwkURI" as a string for URIs and not secrets, since I don't know the correct syntax for it. In Functions I would do something like `context.values` for values, and in Rules I would do `%%user.value`, but neither of those worked for me.

Help would be much appreciated.